# What kind of latch can I use to hang temporary wall panels on a 270 degree angle?

Tags: walls, fastener, temporary

I am building a few temporary wall panels for a little nook in my basement. I would like to be able to put them up and take them down frequently. To do that, I would like to install latches that connect them to the beam running near the ceiling. The panels will be resting on the floor, so the latches don't have to support any weight (aside from preventing them from falling over).

Here is a diagram that shows the structure of the beams I would like to fasten them to. [image]

Please ask if anything needs clarifying. Thank you!

Comment: Magnets? Hook-and-eyes?

Comment: Looks like a 90 degree angle to me. ;)

Comment: Magnets would be nice, but I want something sturdier so they don't fall over if they get bumped. I thought of using hook-and-eyes, but I would like a little bit of tension between the beam and the panels. I would love to call it a 90 degree latch, but searching for those will pull up latches that are the inverse of what I need. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd mount barrel bolts to the beam vertically, then install flat strike plates on top of the panels. If necessary, use shims or bushings to move the bolts out from the beam slightly, leaving them closer to the center of the panels' thickness.

If the panels want to rattle, put a row of thick, soft foam tape on the beam, between it and the panels, to create light tension against the bolts.

Barrel bolt:

[image]

Strike plate:

[image]

Foam tape:

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect solution, +1

Comment: I really like this solution. I think barrel bolts will do nicely, and I hadn't thought of using them this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to attach a filler strip along the beam that matched the thickness of your wall panels ... see below:

[image]

You could use any one of a number of types of catches. One example is this standard type of window casement latch:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The diagram is helpful. I had initially thought of doing this, but seeing as I'm using 2x4s for the panels, the filler strip would have to either 4" thick, or be mounted on both the beam and the panel to be thinner than 4". Ultimately, I will probably use your solution along with the one I selected as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a small hasp with a swivel staple? Mount the "body" of the hasp on the beam. The slotted flap rests at a 90° angle on the staple, which is mounted to the top of the panel. You then simply twist the swiveling staple to secure the panel from falling.

[image]

If the hasp flap is too long, you could put it in a vise and bend it 90° to any length you want, to accommodate for the thickness of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

z- clip

http://www.outwatermastercatalog.com/lg_display.cfm/catalog/2016_Master_Catalog/page/A-34/highlight/z%20clip

one goes on panel.  inverted one goes on beam.  lift panel up and then down on to the clip.  done

Comment: Basically a dual-hook system? This seems viable, but difficult to get right so the panels are flush.

Comment: no, its simple.  you just rabbet out the rear of the panel to the depth of the thickness of the two hooks together.  then everything sits flush when it all mounts together